# How to check GET params authenticity after redirection

Tags: redirect, get, parameters, authenticity

I am working on a project and need a conceptual help.

It allow a website to redirect his user to my web application.
On the web application side the user have to enter some **details** about him, the user is then redirected back to the original website, the **details** are also sent back to the original website using GET params.
The original website can then read the **details**.

Everything work well, but I would like to secure the application, the user should not be able to simply edit the GET params, in fact the website have to check for the authenticity of the params.

Is there any pattern implementation on the web application side and on the original website side in order to secure the GET params.

1. (Website) -> 2. (My Application) -> 3. (Website + details from the application using GET params) = How to check authenticity of the GET params ?

Thanks.